# Problem with solving a system of linear algebraic equations using the relaxation method (lower)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I need your help. The task is to solve a system of linear algebraic equations using the lower relaxation method. But my code only works with matrices up to 3x3, and starting from 4x4 it only works with very small values. And even if you set a small number of iterations for a 4x4 matrix, the result is incorrect numbers that are not even close to the true ones. Help me please...

```
import numpy as np

def relax_solver(A, b, omega, initial_guess, convergence_criteria, stop, itera):
    """
    Solve the system of linear equations using the lower relaxation method.
    Inputs:
        A: nxn numpy matrix
        b: n dimensional numpy vector
        omega: relaxation factor
        initial_guess: an initial solution guess for the solver to start with
        stop: maximum number of iterations.
        itera: a flag that determines whether information about each iteration should be printed
    Returns:
        None
    """
    phi = initial_guess[:]
    residual = np.linalg.norm(np.matmul(A, phi) - b) 
    iteration = 0
    while residual > convergence_criteria and stop > iteration:
        for i in range(A.shape[0]):
            sigma = 0
            for j in range(A.shape[1]):
                if j != i:
                    sigma += A[i][j] * phi[j]
            phi[i] = (1 - omega) * phi[i] + (omega / A[i][i]) * (b[i] - sigma)
        residual = np.linalg.norm(np.matmul(A, phi) - b)
        iteration += 1
        if itera == True:
            print(f'Iteration {iteration}, Solution: {", ".join(f"{val:.15f}" for val in phi)}')
            
    print("Solution:", ", ".join(f"{val:.15f}" for val in phi))
    print(f"Number of iterations: {iteration}")
```

Tried it with this input data:

```
A = np.array([[5, 8, -3, 21],
              [-3, 4, 0.5, -8.7],
              [-3.6, 0.34, 3, -76],
              [-5.7, 2.26, -5.6, 9]])

B = np.array([-6, 4, 45, -15], dtype=float)
```

Comment: Please show what matrices and vectors you are calling this with. Note that (relaxed or unrelaxed) Gauss-Seidel is only guaranteed to work if it is diagonally dominant. However, for the matrices that I tried it worked fine.

Comment: A = np.array([[5, 8, -3, 21],
              [-3, 4, 0.5, -8.7],
              [-3.6, 0.34, 3, -76],
              [-5.7, 2.26, -5.6, 9]])

B = np.array([-6, 4, 45, -15], dtype=float)

Comment: @Merlin can you please give outputs of this both correct and incorrect one

Comment: I tried setting the residual convergence as 1e-5, the relaxation factor as 0.5, and the number of steps as 200. As a result, it outputs very large numbers with a large number of decimal places. If I set the number of steps to more than 500, the result becomes even larger and the compiler generates an overflow error.

Comment: Sorry, there's one more question. A singular matrix is one which determinant is equal zero. I calculated the determinant of this matrix and it is equal to -18394. Is the matrix singular?

Comment: @Merlin, I think you just have a very badly-conditioned matrix. Under- (or over-) relaxed Gauss-Seidel work best when you have a diagonally-dominant matrix, and yours is a long way from that. There are plenty of other matrices that your routine works fine for.

Comment: It turns out there are no errors in the code?

Comment: I can't see any errors in the code (as long as it's intended to be an implementation of Gauss-Seidel). It works fine for the sort of matrices that Gauss-Seidel is reasonable to use for. Just not your particular example.